# Unclear type of an input to algebraic circuit

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

How $i=1,...,n$
is an input for a circuit $A$?

I thought that inputs are strings from $\{0,1\}^n$ and not $i$'s; see below.

[image]

Comment: A guess : If $A=\in \{0,1\}^n$ then you can write $A=0100110$ for instance, and the $A(i)$ represents the $i$th position, such that in this example, $A(1)=0$, $A(2)=1$, ... Still in this example if $x=0100$, then $A\to x$.